¿Cómo se usa vgnexport y vgnimport para exportar e importar contenidos de OpenText Vignette?
Estoy intentando exportar una serie de contenidos de mi OpenText 8.1 y tengo a mi disposición los scripts de vgnexport y vgnimport que vienen con el producto de Vignette. Que básicamente sirven para exportar e importar contenidos de OpenText en formato XML.
He conseguido exportar un único contenido usando su ID, pero si quiero exportar todos los contenidos que se encuentran en una misma ruta no puedo porque no sé cuales son todos los parámetros que hay que decirle.
/<rutacompleta>/VCM/Content/8_1/bin/vgnexport -h <host:puerto> -u <user> -p <pass> -i <ID> -f ./contenidoExportado.zip -l ./contenidoExportado.log
¿Como sería para poder exportar todos aquellos contenidos que se encuentren en la misma ruta?

Me respondo a mí mismo porque he encontrado la solución a lo que buscaba en la documentación de Vignette, concretamente en el pdf "Vignette Content Administration Guide" que solo lo tengo en local.
El comando final con el que he conseguido exportar los contenidos que quería ha sido así:
./vgnexport -h <host:puerto> -u <user> -p <pass> -n <rutalogicalPath> -t project -f ./contenidosExportados.zip -l ./contenidosExportados.log -c errorPolicy=continue -c resultsLevel=all -c channelAssocs=false -c subChannels=false -c contentTypeRefs=false
En vez de usar la opción -i para indicar el ID he usado la opción -t project para indicar que lo que quiero es el directorio junto a la opción -n para indicar el nombre del directorio que quiero.
También he añadido una serie de parámetros -c, aunque técnicamente no me hacen falta no están de más.
Respecto a la documentación de vgnexport y vgnimport si no la encontráis dejo un resumen de lo que dice:
Tabla de Opciones para vgnexport y vgnimport



Opciones del script
Requerido
Descripción
Script




-c key=value
No
Aplica la clave especificada a todos los objetos del comando actual. Claves válidas incluyen acls, channelAssocs, classifications, contentTypeRefs, errorPolicy, projectContent, resultsLevel, schedulingDates, subChannels, subPreferences, subProjects, suppressWorkflows
Ambos


-d description
No
Inserta una descripción de texto en el archivo del paquete. La descripción debe estar entre comillas.
vgnexport


-D key=value
No
Establece la propiedad de la clase del sistema Java identificada por la clave con el valor especificado.
Ambos


-f pkgpath
Sí
Especifica la ubicación del archivo del paquete.
Ambos


-h host:port
Sí
Especifica el nombre de host y el número de puerto del servidor VCM.
Ambos


-i objectid
Sí*
Especifica el ID de contenido Vignette de un solo objeto a ser agregado al archivo del paquete.
vgnexport


-l logfile
No
Genera un archivo de registro en la ubicación especificada.
Ambos


-m manifest
Sí*
Especifica la ubicación del archivo de manifiesto del paquete a ser utilizado como fuente de datos del objeto.
vgnexport


-n name
Sí*
Especifica el nombre de un único objeto a ser agregado al archivo del paquete. Debe usarse junto con -t.
vgnexport


-p password
Sí
Contraseña para iniciar sesión en el servidor VCM (autenticar al usuario). Si no se proporciona una contraseña, el comando la solicitará.
Ambos


-s
No
En lugar de realizar la importación, devuelve una encuesta de recursos mostrando las fuentes de archivos, fuentes de datos, widgets y oyentes de eventos necesarios en el servidor VCM de destino antes de importar.
vgnimport


-t type
Sí*
Especifica el tipo de un único objeto para exportar. Debe usarse junto con -n. Tipos válidos incluyen site, channel, project, objectType, contentType, staticFile, workflow, programTask, configNode, preferences.
vgnexport


-u username
Sí
Especifica un usuario autorizado para iniciar sesión en el servidor VCM (autenticar al usuario).
Ambos


-x optionsfile
No
Identifica un archivo XML que proporciona valores para cualquier opción listada en esta tabla. Si una opción se especifica tanto en el archivo de opciones como en la línea de comando, prevalecerá el valor de la línea de comando.
Ambos


-z chunksize
No
Especifica el número de objetos a exportar por solicitud del servidor interno.
Ambos




Las opciones con * significa que es obligatorio poner una de esas opciones, es decir, si se usa una las demás no se pueden usar, a excepción de las opciones -n y -t que deben usarse juntas.

Tabla de Valores para -c key=value



Clave
Valores Aceptables
Descripción




acls
true (por defecto), false
Incluye o excluye la información de la Lista de Control de Acceso (ACL) para cada objeto en la exportación o importación.


channelAssocs
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se deben exportar o importar las asociaciones de canal.


classifications
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se debe exportar o importar la información de clasificación de taxonomía de cada objeto.


conflictPolicy
ignore, overwrite, version (por defecto)
Determina la acción a tomar si un objeto ya existe en el servidor VCM de destino durante la importación.


contentTypeRefs
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se deben exportar o importar las referencias de tipo de contenido.


errorPolicy
stop (por defecto), continue
Acción a tomar cuando ocurre un error durante el procesamiento.


ignoreMissingChannels
true, false (por defecto)
Especifica si las asociaciones de canal deben ser ignoradas si no se encuentran en el servidor VCM de destino.


projectContent
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se deben exportar o importar los contenidos de los proyectos.


resultsLevel
all, info (por defecto), error, none
Nivel de detalle del estado que se debe mostrar o registrar al completar la exportación o importación.


schedulingDates
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si las fechas de publicación y despublicación programadas deben exportarse o importarse.


structuralChangesAllowed
true, false (por defecto)
Permite cambios estructurales en definiciones de tipo de contenido durante la importación.


subChannels
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se deben exportar o importar los subcanales.


subPreferences
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se deben exportar o importar las subpreferencias de los usuarios.


subProjects
true (por defecto), false
Especifica si se deben exportar o importar los subproyectos.


suppressWorkflows
true (suprimir flujos de trabajo), false (por defecto, no suprimir)
Especifica si se deben suprimir los flujos de trabajo de los objetos durante la importación.


tolerateContentError
true (por defecto), false
Solo relevante si errorPolicy está establecido en continue. Si un contenido falla, permite que otros objetos en el grupo continúen procesándose.


versionComment
Cadena de texto
Permite especificar un comentario al crear versiones de objetos. Relevante solo si conflictPolicy está establecido en version. Si no se especifica, se usa una cadena predeterminada.



